# Responsive datatables inside accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Tables</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> 
            <div class="panel-group panel-group-joined" id="accordion-test"> 
                <div class="panel panel-default"> 
                    <div class="panel-heading main s-2" >
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-test" href="#s-2" class="collapsed">AAA</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="s-2" class="panel-collapse  collapse s-2">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>ELEMENT</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <table id="datatable-responsive-table-io-v-2" data-type-secteur="1" class="io-table-1 datatable-responsive table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">L</th>
                                                    <th>T</th>
                                                    <th>S</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">V</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">D</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">Temp</th>
                                                    <th>Time</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="readingVal">V1</td>
                                                    <td>R1</td>
                                                    <td>S1</td>
                                                    <td class="3-5">-10.4</td>
                                                    <td class="diff-3-5">3</td>
                                                    <td class="Temp-5">-18.1</td>
                                                    <td class="Time-5">20286</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="readingVal">V2</td>
                                                    <td>R2</td>
                                                    <td>S2</td>
                                                    <td class="3-1">-8</td>
                                                    <td class="diff-3-1">5.4</td>
                                                    <td class="Temp-1">-17.4</td>
                                                    <td class="Time-1">20286</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>   <!-- closing panel-body radio -->
                                </div>  <!-- closing panel-default radio -->
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="panel-heading main s-4" >
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-test" href="#s-4" class="collapsed">BBB</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="s-4" class="panel-collapse  collapse s-4">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>ELEMENT</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <table id="datatable-responsive-table-io-v-4" data-type-secteur="1" class="io-table-1 datatable-responsive table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">L</th>
                                                    <th>T</th>
                                                    <th>S</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">V</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">D</th>
                                                    <th data-priority="1">Temp</th>
                                                    <th>Time</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="readingVal">V11</td>
                                                    <td>R11</td>
                                                    <td>S1</td>
                                                    <td class="3-5">-10.4</td>
                                                    <td class="diff-3-5">3</td>
                                                    <td class="Temp-5">-18.1</td>
                                                    <td class="Time-5">20286</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="readingVal">V22</td>
                                                    <td>R22</td>
                                                    <td>S2</td>
                                                    <td class="3-1">-8</td>
                                                    <td class="diff-3-1">5.4</td>
                                                    <td class="Temp-1">-17.4</td>
                                                    <td class="Time-1">20286</td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>   <!-- closing panel-body radio -->
                                </div>  <!-- closing panel-default radio -->
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
$("[id^='datatable-responsive-table-io-v-']").DataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "responsive": true,
  "colReorder": true,
  "stateSave": true
});

$('#s-2').collapse('show');
```

I've datatables inside bootstrap accordion. When I resize the result screen to be smaller than the table and then I re-run the script, I can see that the datatable is not resized. But if I resize the screen after, then, the table is redrawn with the responsiveness... (like if the screen is doing a refresh)

Please see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sincos/uwoc8qdu/2/)

If I add this :

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $(window).trigger('resize') }, 750);                 
});
```

it will resize the datatable with the accordion opened (if all the accordion are opened, they will be all resize, if only one, only this one will be resize. If I open the accordion after this, the table is not resized...)

[jsFiddle with resize window](https://jsfiddle.net/sincos/uwoc8qdu/3/)

I've tried several thing. Like this :

```
$("[id^='s-']")
   .collapse('show')
   .on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(window).trigger('resize');
   });
```

[jsFiddle with resizing on shown](https://jsfiddle.net/sincos/uwoc8qdu/4/)

It works partially. But I'm not sure it is the good way to do this... And also, I was not able to collapse all tabs except the first one and when I open a tab, the other one is supposed to close - like the first jsFiddle (at the end, I want the first tab open and the table to be resized)

Hope I'm clear in my explanation.

Comment: try by calling `$('#s-2').collapse('show');` before your dataTable is it help ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq only for the current opened accordion. The other one (which is hidden) the table is not resized...

Comment: exactly the it won't thats why i am saying try calling `collapse('show')` before DataTable initialize